# write line with constant or variable values every X number of characters in vim

Tags: vim, insert, line, cursor-position

Is there a way to write a new line in vim which inserts constant or variable values every X number of characters? I would like to include a line in the data block of a nexus file with a separator `|` every 10 characters. I would also like to insert the character number above this. Here is an example of what I would like to produce:

```
1         11        21        31        41
|         |         |         |         | 
CAACGTGCGACTTGAAGGACATGATCGGTTGTGGGTTCTTA
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For adding a `|` every 10th character, you could use `%s/\v\w{10}\zs/|/g`